# ValueError: X.shape[1] = 772 should be equal to 676, the number of features at training time

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, sparse-matrix, valueerror

I have a problem with one-class SVM. Because of the dense matrices are too large, I am using sparse matrices to train and test my dataset. When I use  `predict` function, code gives error like

> ValueError: X.shape[1] = 772 should be equal to 676, the number of features at training time

When I decrease samples on test data, it works with a zero accuracy rate. What is the problem with that?

I know, there was some advices like use `values.shape` function or use `n_features` argument but one-class SVM does not contain `n_features` argument and sparse matrices does not accept `values.shape`.

```
o_svm = OneClassSVM()
o_svm.fit(concating_data_train)
anomaly_detect = o_svm.predict(concating_data_test)

 #concating datas are similar; 
concating_data_test = hstack((concating_test_non_numeric, standardization_sparse_data_test_numeric))
```

Comment: The error refers to the number of *features*, not samples. You sure have prepared your test data the same way as your training ones?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I guess the problem with this about sparse matrix logic. They compress zeros, so for encoding process for each dataset, it gets different length of matrices.